# Necessary and sufficient conditions for a bijection to exist

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question

Suppose we have two sets $A$ and $B$. Suppose there exists injections $i_1:A\to B$ and $i_2:B\to A$. Does there exist a bijection from $A$ to $B$? Does a bijection exist if and only if $A$ and $B$ are finite?

This is a question I have been thinking about for a while and cannot make much progress on it. What, if any, would be the necessary and sufficient conditions on the sets $A,B$ or functions $i_1,i_2$ for there to exist a bijection from $A$ to $B$? Any tips or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Bijection can exist between two infinite sets like two line segments.

Comment: or $\mathbb N$ and $\mathbb Z$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Schröder–Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem?wprov=sfti1).

Comment: I came here to say this. You don’t like giving Cantor credit? Lol

Comment: @RiversMcForge Strangely, we théorème de Cantor Bernstein in French, but it is called Schröder Bernstein in Wikipedia and usually in English if I’m not mistaking.

Comment: I’ve always heard it called C-B-S in that order, but according to Wiki, it’s S and B who deserve credit, at least as far as formal demonstration: *“The theorem is named after Felix Bernstein and Ernst Schröder. It is also known as Cantor–Bernstein theorem, or Cantor–Schröder–Bernstein, after Georg Cantor who first published it without proof.”*

Comment: in the proof given on the wikipedia page, if you don't mind explaining, what was the constructed bijection?

Comment: never mind, I think I figured it out. Thank you for giving me the name of the theorem